# ReactJS & Redux access state "constructor" from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm just trying to post a data everything working fine if I put the fetch function in the same file but when I moved it to another file it shows cannot read property, I've tried this.props instead of this.state, how can I connect this file to constructor()

[image]

**scr/component/layout.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'; 
import { fetchUsers, postUsers } from '../actions/usersAction';


class Layout extends Component {
constructor(){
    super() 
    this.state = {  
        name: '',
        age: ''}
}

onUserUpdate(filed, event){
    console.log('onUserUpdate: ' + filed + '==' + event.target.value);
    if (filed == 'name') {
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value
        })
        return
    }
    if (filed == 'age') {
        this.setState({
            age: event.target.value
        })
        return
    }
}


componentDidMount() {  
  this.props.fetchUsers();
}
  render() {

    const { act } = this.props;

      const fetchUserss = act.users.map(d =>  <tr key={d.id}><td>{d.name}</td><td>{d.age}</td></tr>);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <label>
            name:
              </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.onUserUpdate.bind(this, 'name')} placeholder="Enter Name"/>
                <label>
                age:
              </label>
                <input type="text" name="age" onChange={this.onUserUpdate.bind(this, 'age')} placeholder="enter username"/>
                <button type="simpleQuery" onClick={this.props.postUsers.bind(this)}>Add News</button>
    
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                 {fetchUserss}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
  }
}



function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        act: state.users,
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({fetchUsers, postUsers}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Layout);
```

**src/actions/userAction.js**

```
export const fetchUsers = (data) =>{
            return{
            type: "USERS",
            payload: fetch('http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends',{
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
                
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
    }
};
export const postUsers = (event) =>{
    let users = {
        name: this.state.name,
        age: this.state.age
    }
    return{
            type: "USERS_POST",
            payload: fetch('http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends',{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(users),
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
    }
};
```

**src/reducers/userReducer.js**

```
const initalState = {
fetching: false,
fetched: false,
users: [],
error: null
};
export default function(state=initalState, action) {
    let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
    switch(action.type){
        case "USERS_PENDING":{
            return {...state, fetching: true,loading: false,}
        }
        case "USERS_FULFILLED":{
            return {...state, fetching:false, fetched: true, users: action.payload,}
        }
        case "USERS_REJECTED":{
            return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload,}
        }
        case "USERS_POST_PENDING":{
            return {...state, fetching: true,}
        }
        case "USERS_POST_FULFILLED":{
              return newState;
        }
        case "USERS_POST_REJECTED":{
            return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload,}
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I miss out any information.

If this has already been asked, I would greatly appreciate if you are able to point me in the right direction.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass that data to your `postUsers()` function.

```
<button 
  type="simpleQuery" 
  onClick={() => this.props.postUsers(this.state.name,this.state.age)}
>Add News</button>
```

Then in your `postUsers()` function should take in those parameters:

```
export const postUsers = (name, age) => ({
  type: "USERS_POST",
  payload: fetch('http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name,
      age,
    }),
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
});
```

Comment: Thank you it works, may I know why the date doesn't appear immediately?

Comment: The date? I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot access state outside of a component. You can pass the state variables are params to the postUsers function.

```
<button type="simpleQuery" onClick={this.props.postUsers(this.state.name,this.state.age)}>Add News</button>
```

And in your postUsers function

```
export const postUsers = (name,age) =>{
let users = {
    name: name,
    age: age
}
return{
        type: "USERS_POST",
        payload: fetch('http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(users),
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
}
```

};

Comment: It keeps refreshing

Comment: This is the best way, the error you are getting is because of some other problem

Comment: He's getting an error because you're calling the function instead of passing a reference to it. The function needs to be called when the click event happens, not before. It should be `onClick={() => this.props.postUser(this.state.name, this.state.age)}`

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you have tried to bind a scope to an arrow function. You cannot do that. Arrow functions do not have a scope.

Instead, you should write a normal function.

either,

```
let postUsers = function() {};
```

or

```
function postUsers(){}
```

In other words `this` inside an arrow function is always inherited from the parent function. So in your case, `this` is not `undefined`, but it is not the `this` you expect.

Comment: I did the way you told me thank you, but unfortunately, it doesn't fixed my problem.

Comment: @Liamm12 Then maybe your code had more than 1 problem. The scope issue is definitely one of them. Let me check if there are other issues.